# Can I use CoffeeScript instead of JS for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

What are my restrictions if I want to code node.js and use CoffeeScript?
Can I do anything I'd be able to do in JS?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Yes, CoffeeScript simply compiles into pure JS, making it completely compatible with node.js.

To run CoffeeScripts on node, you can either:

- Type `coffee -c example.coffee` to compile, followed by `node example.js` to run the compiled JS.
- Simply type `coffee example.coffee`

Comment: @donald, I'm not aware of any combined CoffeeScript + Node tutorials. Learning them separately is ideal. The link I gave above for Node is a perfect introduction, and for CoffeeScript, this is all you need: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Comment: @donald here, try this one: http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/16-introduction-to-coffeescript-and-nodejs.html#video

Comment: But what about when using other CoffeeScript files? I don't want to put everything in 1 CoffeeScript

Comment: @Jiew Meng you can compile a whole directory in the same way (replace example.coffee with the directory path), or you can `require` uncompiled coffeescript files as long as you `require('coffee-script')` beforehand.

Comment: Is running `coffee example.coffee` primarily for development? Or is it stable enough to do in production?

Comment: Yeah, what's the difference between the two choices?

Comment: To install coffee `sudo npm install -g coffee-script`

Comment: worth pointing out - I've found in some cases that only the version coffee example.coffee will work - worth giving that a shot before you try to debug javascript exceptions

Answer (score 90):

Not only can you run CoffeeScript files directly in Node with

```
coffee source.coffee
```

you can also require them as if they were JavaScript files. For instance, if you have `lib.coffee` in a directory, you can write

```
require './lib'
```

from another CoffeeScript file in the same directory. (In order to do this from a JavaScript file, you'll have to add `require 'coffee-script'` at the top.) So, you never have to do compilation explicitly under Node, unless you're packaging your project for deployment with a tool like npm.

One caveat: In stack traces, the line numbers you'll see refer to the compiled JavaScript, even when you're running CoffeeScript directly (so you don't have access to the JavaScript). A lot of folks are trying to fix this, but it's a big challenge.

Comment: What happens with client-side coffee/js?

Comment: client-side needs ad interpreter you have to include in HTML page.

Comment: @fancy, coffescript > 1.6.1 [supports source maps](http://coffeescript.org/#source-maps)

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not able to be debugged without correlating JS to coffee in your head.

Comment: Coffeescript to JS conversion rules are pretty simple, they are all well documented :)

Comment: Since CoffeeScript 1.7.0 you have to load it as follows: `require('coffee-script/register');` ([Source](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/issues/138))

Answer (score 57):

Yes, here's a different & simpler answer. You need to do 2 steps.

1. `npm install coffee-script --save # I assume you would have done this already`.
2. Have `require('coffee-script')` as the first line that would get executed in `server.js` of `app.js`. (**UPDATE:** since coffee script 1.7, you will have to do `require('coffee-script/register'))`

This registers coffeescript compiler to your app and you can start treating coffee files and js files equally now (meaning that you can require coffee files too !).

This method will require you to write just the one file (app.js) in vanilla javascript. But the advantage is that your deploy environment need not have coffeescript as an initial globally installed dependency to run your app. In this case, you would just have to copy over your code, and `npm install` would install all packages necessary. And `npm start` would have you up and running

Comment: Thanks for the note about the 1.7 update @gprasant, I was pulling my hair out wondering why this stopped working.

Answer (score 15):

**Video Tutorials**

I've seen a great tutorial series by *Pedro Teixeira*. He's been building an entire series on node tutorials. He includes reference to nodemon for auto detection and compilation and reloading of edited .coffee files.

1. [Coffeescript and Node.js](http://vimeo.com/18429839)
2. [Nodemon](http://vimeo.com/18125866)

Comment: The http://nodetuts.com/ links above are broken.  The tutorials on that site look great, though.

Comment: thanks, the original link destinations vanished/moved. Set them to what google search revealed, the Vimeo videos @countfloortiles

Comment: See http://brunch.io for a great NodeJS daemon / asset pipeline solution.  Covers Coffee, CSS supersets and more.

Comment: spotted this a while back, but haven't visited since. thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Jitter](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/Jitter), a Simple continuous compilation for CoffeeScript.

```
npm install -g jitter
```

Let's say you have a bunch of *.coffee files in the coffee directory, and want to compile them to the js directory. Then run:

```
jitter coffee js
```

Jitter runs in the background until you terminate it (Ctrl+C), watching for new changes.

Answer (score 8):

Coffeescript + ExpressJS + Couchdb + Redis + Auth:

https://gist.github.com/652819

Comment: Damn, that's a lot of buzzwords.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
v = 78
console.log "The value of v is '#{v}'"
```

Then do:

```
chmod +x demo.coffee
./demo.coffee
```

CoffeeScript has pretty solid integration with node.  Once the 'coffee-script' module is loaded, either by `require('coffee-script')`, by the she-bang I demo'd above, or by running `coffee demo.coffee` ... once loaded, you can used `require('./foo')` to bring in `foo.coffee`

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically compile all your coffeescript files (in one directory including subdir) every time they change into javascript, just use this command:

```
find . -name '*.coffee' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 coffee -wc
```

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in coffeescript functionality?
`coffee -o lib/ -cw src/`