# Can I run a .coffee file directly from node.js?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm doing some tutorials and I'm writing everything in CoffeeScript. I then have to compile to JS then execute in node.js. Is there any way to do it directly?

Comment: See Trevor Burnham's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679782/can-i-use-coffeescript-instead-of-js-for-node-js)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have npm, use it to install coffeescript from a node prompt: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffeescript/#installation

Then, from the node prompt, you can simply use the coffee command to execute:

```
coffee <yourcoffeescriptfile>.coffee
```

And, to just compile, pass the `-c` flag:

```
coffee -c <yourcoffeescriptfile>.coffee
```

Comment: Also note that you can `require('./foo')` from a Node module to bring in `foo.coffee`, provided that you've already run `require('coffee-script')` (which you get for free when you run Node from the `coffee` command); it adds a hook to the `require` function. So mixing and matching `.coffee` and `.js` files in a Node app is very simple.

Comment: Some more info on the use of `-c`: the compilation results are saved to a `.js` file with the same filename root in the same folder as the input file, unless `-o` is used to specify a different folder. Use `-p` to print the resulting JavaScript to `stdout` instead; run `coffee -h` to see all options.

Comment: The repo has been renamed to `coffeescript` so the link should be https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/#installation

Answer (score 56):

Yes you can.

```
coffee source.coffee -n
```

It will run Node directly without generating any .js files.

[Reference](http://coffeescript.org/#usage)

**Update**:
Coffee now also supports `--nodejs`.  The above does the same as

```
coffee source.coffee --nodejs
```

But yeah, `-n` is way shorter.

Comment: Lol, my bad. Hope it helps though. I will take that comment back.

Comment: Great; I assume the `-n` is just an example parameter to pass to the script invoked, correct?

Comment: @arvidkahl  read the doc, seems --nodejs is just a prefix for passing in node options. will test it out tonight, thx

Comment: @arvidkahl `--nodejs` works and it's able to do a lot more. But if you just want to simply execute, `-n' is way shorter :)

Comment: @yujingz `-n` is a different, unrelated option.  You don't need any command line options to just run a CoffeeScript file in Node.

Comment: hey @EricW i understand that, maybe my previous statement is misleading. I just want to say `-n` is shorter not to mean its the abbreviation of `--nodejs`

Comment: I think the options comes before the file, so this answer is essentially the same as `$ coffee source.coffee`