# Merge coffeescript into your node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Is setting a bunch of watchers to compile to js still the best approach in development or is there something more elegant?

I'm looking for techniques or packages that handle CoffeeScript in development and make it really nice instead of just watching and compiling to another js folder. Anything out there?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4683431/838871)'s an answer that briefly explains how to use CS without compiling it manually to JS. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh awesome.... +1 Ivan, thanks this is a good start! Does this work for client side js being servered too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## node.js server code in CoffeeScript

So for writing your node.js server code, you don't need to do anything special. Just start your app with `coffee server.coffee` instead of `node server.js` and coffeescript will transpile your code to javascript on the fly without ever needing to write `.js` files to disk.

## Browser code in CoffeeScript (Basic)

For taking `.coffee` files on disk and serving the transpiled `.js` files to the browser, you can use the `coffee-script` node module to do the transpiling and serve the output. Coding it manually is just a few lines, but those few lines already exist as [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) compatible middleware. Use the [connect-coffee-script](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-connect-coffee-script) module. There are basic examples at that link, but it boils down to `app.use(connectCoffeeScript({src: "#{__dirname}/public"}))` or some variation thereof. This is compatible with [express](http://expressjs.com) version 3.x. When a request for a `.js` URL comes in, the middleware will locate the corresponding `.coffee` file and transpile it from `src` to `dest` if needed. You should have the connect static middleware configured to serve files from your `dest` directory further down your middleware chain and it will be the connect static middleware that actually servers the `.js` file to the browser.

## Full-on Asset Management

For a more advanced solution including dependency management, cache busting, concatenation, minifaction, etc, etc inspired by the Ruby on Rails asset pipeline, you can use [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets). It's a more complex solution, but the asset management problem in general is complex and this will fully solve many of the tricky problems for you. This will handle CoffeeScript for JS, Stylus for CSS as well as other transpilers and preprocessors.

Comment: awesome, so `enable: ["coffeescript"]` does the same as `coffee app.coffee` but for client-side stuff?

Comment: express.compiler() no longer exists but you can use https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets to do automatic coffeescript compilation now