# What's the best way to do asset management with node?

Tags: node.js

I'm building a set of one-page applications. I want all the resources that app needs to be delivered in one big initial payload.

Each version gets it's own asset package but they are all a part of the same parent app.

What is the best way to set something like this up to deliver sets of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[connect asset manager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager) (click the link to the docs) will combine separate CSS/JS files into a single file, compress them, convert images to base64 for embedding with data URIs into your CSS files, minify the code, etc

From the README:

What does it allow you to do?

- Merge and minify CSS/javascript files
- Auto regenerates the cache on file change so no need for restart of server or manual action.
- Run pre/post manipulation on the files
- Use regex to match user agent so you can serve different modified versions of your packed assets based on the requesting browser.
- Supplies a reference to the modified dates for all groups through assetManager().cacheTimestamps[groupName] as well as md5 hashes assetManager().cacheHashes[groupName] which can be used for cache invalidation in templates.
  Wildcard add files from dir

Comment: Will this compile coffee script?

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation about what connect asset manager does?

Comment: @fancy no, this won't compile coffeescript files for you, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998742/merge-coffeescript-into-your-node-project/8999072#8999072 for how to use express middleware to compile coffescript on the fly.

Comment: @PeterLyons Compile and then add into this asset manager? I'm looking to get to one js file and one css file.

Comment: I think you can use the connect assetmanager hooks to compile coffeescript to javascript as the assets are built. Give it a shot. It's built to address your goal.

Comment: It can compile coffeescript for you. You can pass in a compile function that does whatever you want to a file. I write one when I was using it, I'll look for it.

Comment: Here https://gist.github.com/1679405