# Create an array of characters from specified range

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js

I read some code where someone did this in Ruby:

```
puts ('A'..'Z').to_a.join(',')
```

output:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
```

Is there something in `Javascript` that will allow this to be done just as easy? if not, is there Node module that allows for something similar?

Comment: `var arr=[]; for (var idx='A'.charCodeAt(0),end='Z'.charCodeAt(0); idx <=end; ++idx){arr.push(String.fromCharCode(idx));} arr.join();`

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I'd need to use a for loop.

Comment: You can use a while loop if you prefer that ;)

Comment: It seems what I want is "range" which isn't supported in Javascript, although it seems a lot of other languages support it.

Comment: [...Array(26).keys()].map( (_, i) => String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i) )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have that functionality natively. Below you find some examples of how it could be solved:

Normal function, any characters from the base plane (no checking for surrogate pairs)

```
function range(start,stop) {
  var result=[];
  for (var idx=start.charCodeAt(0),end=stop.charCodeAt(0); idx <=end; ++idx){
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(idx));
  }
  return result;
};

range('A','Z').join();
```

The same as above, but as a function added to the array prototype, and therefore available to all arrays:

```
Array.prototype.add_range = function(start,stop) {
  for (var idx=start.charCodeAt(0),end=stop.charCodeAt(0); idx <=end; ++idx){
    this.push(String.fromCharCode(idx));
  }
  return this;
};

[].add_range('A','Z').join();
```

A range from preselected characters. Is faster than the functions above, and let you use `alphanum_range('A','z')` to mean A-Z and a-z:

```
var alphanum_range = (function() {
  var data = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'.split('');
  return function (start,stop) {
    start = data.indexOf(start);
    stop = data.indexOf(stop);
    return (!~start || !~stop) ? null : data.slice(start,stop+1);
  };
})();

alphanum_range('A','Z').join();
```

Or any character from the ascii range. By using a cached array, it is faster than the functions that build the array every time.

```
var ascii_range = (function() {
  var data = [];
  while (data.length < 128) data.push(String.fromCharCode(data.length));
  return function (start,stop) {
    start = start.charCodeAt(0);
    stop = stop.charCodeAt(0);
    return (start < 0 || start > 127 || stop < 0 || stop > 127) ? null : data.slice(start,stop+1);
  };
})();

ascii_range('A','Z').join();
```

Answer (score 29):

If you're using ES6, you can generate a sequence using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) by passing in an array-like object for the length of the range, and a map function as a second argument to convert the array key of each item in the range into a character using String.fromCharCode():

```
Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i));
```

You can also use the Array constructor (note: ES6 allows constructors to be invoked either with a function call or with the `new` operator) to initialize an array of the desired default length, fill it using [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), then map through it:

```
Array(26).fill().map((_, i) => String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i));
```

The same can be accomplished with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
[...Array(26)].map((_, i) => String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i));
```

The above three examples will return an array with characters from A to Z. For custom ranges, you can adjust the length and starting character.

For browsers that don't support ES6, you can use babel-polyfill or core-js polyfill (core-js/fn/array/from).

If you're targeting ES5, I would recommend the [Array.apply solution by @wires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980914/1526145) which is very similar to this one.

Lastly, Underscore/Lodash and Ramda have a range() function:

```
_.range('A'.charCodeAt(0), 'Z'.charCodeAt(0) + 1).map(i => String.fromCharCode(i));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var chars = [].concat.apply([], Array(26))
              .map(function(_, i) { return String.fromCharCode(i+65); })
              .join();
```

The `.map` function could be a function generator that could be used for different character sets.

```
function charRange(start) {
    var base = start.charCodeAt(0);
    return function(_, i) { return String.fromCharCode(i + base); };
}
```

And you may also want to create a "full" Array helper.

```
function fullArray(len) { return [].concat.apply([], Array(len)); }
```

Then use them like this.

```
var chars = fullArray(26).map(charRange("A"))
                         .join();
```

Comment: Nice, functional style is IMO waaaay more readable than for loop based answers. This answers deserves more upvotes

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

```
// ['a', .. , 'z']
Array.apply(null, {length: 26})
    .map(function (x,i) { return String.fromCharCode(97 + i) });
```

Or even

```
function range(first, last) {
    var a = first.charCodeAt(0)
    var b = last.charCodeAt(0) + 1
    return Array.apply(null, {length: Math.abs(b - a)})
      .map(function (x,i) { return String.fromCharCode(Math.min(a, b) + i) });
}
range('K','M') // => ['K','L','M']
range('$','z') // => "$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

---

I think this can be expressed clearest in a functional way: map `[0 .. 25]` to `['a' .. 'z']`.

We can use `fromCharCode(n)` to convert a number into a string. To find the numerical value corresponding to a character we need it's inverse function, `toCharCode(s)`:

```
var toCharCode = function(s){ return s.charCodeAt(0) } // 'a' => 97, 'b' => 98, ..
```

Then the rest is easy:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 26})
     .map(function (x,i) { return String.fromCharCode(97 + i) });
```

Constructs an array of 26 undefined's: `[undefined, ... , undefined]`. Then `map` index `i` of each value to `97 + i` == `'a'.charCodeAt(0) + i` (for uppercase start at `'A' => 65`).

This first line might need some explanation. What we are effectively doing is the same as `Array(1,2,3)` == `[1,2,3]`. Instead of passing an actual array to `apply`, we pass something that quacks like an array (has the `length` property). This results in calling `Array(undefined, .. , undefined)`.

See 
[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
and 
["generic array-like object"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Working_with_Array-like_objects)
for more infomation.

Comment: FYI the range for all ASCII characters is `range(' ','~')` -- thanks for this function!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the answer from kannebec for a similar question.

[Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate an array based on supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-range-equivalent/3895618#3895618)

If you don't want to add an own function, but in one line:

```
var abc = 
(function(){var output = []; for(var i='A'.charCodeAt(0); i <= 'Z'.charCodeAt(0); i++)
    output.push(String.fromCharCode(i)); return output;})().join(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

[CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) compiles to javascript, and it has numeric ranges:

```
(String.fromCharCode(x+64) for x in [1..26]).join(",")
```

[Here's a link](http://coffeescript.org/#try:result%20=%20%28String.fromCharCode%28x+64%29%20for%20x%20in%20%5B1..26%5D%29.join%28%22,%22%29%0Aalert%20result) to this script in the coffeescript.org site. You can see what javascript it compiles to, and run it in your browser live.

(And [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679782/can-i-use-coffeescript-instead-of-js-for-node-js), you can use coffeescript for Node.js)

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different approach

```
String.fromCharCode(..." ".repeat(26).split("").map((e,i)=>i+'A'.charCodeAt()))
```

prints

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Comment: This is the way a Sring master thinks. A lot of cool answers, reflecting different ways of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599169/8784402

#### Generate Character List with one-liner

```js
const charList = (a,z,d=1)=>(a=a.charCodeAt(),z=z.charCodeAt(),[...Array(Math.floor((z-a)/d)+1)].map((_,i)=>String.fromCharCode(a+i*d)));

console.log("from A to G", charList('A', 'G'));
console.log("from A to Z with step/delta of 2", charList('A', 'Z', 2));
console.log("reverse order from Z to P", charList('Z', 'P', -1));
console.log("from 0 to 5", charList('0', '5', 1));
console.log("from 9 to 5", charList('9', '5', -1));
console.log("from 0 to 8 with step 2", charList('0', '8', 2));
console.log("from α to ω", charList('α', 'ω'));
console.log("Hindi characters from क to ह", charList('क', 'ह'));
console.log("Russian characters from А to Я", charList('А', 'Я'));
```

For TypeScript

```
const charList = (p: string, q: string, d = 1) => {
  const a = p.charCodeAt(0),
    z = q.charCodeAt(0);
  return [...Array(Math.floor((z - a) / d) + 1)].map((_, i) =>
    String.fromCharCode(a + i * d)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function will help you.

```
function range ( low, high, step ) {    // Create an array containing a range of elements
    // 
    // +   original by: _argos

    var matrix = [];
    var inival, endval, plus;
    var walker = step || 1;
    var chars  = false;

    if ( !isNaN ( low ) && !isNaN ( high ) ) {
        inival = low;
        endval = high;
    } else if ( isNaN ( low ) && isNaN ( high ) ) {
        chars = true;
        inival = low.charCodeAt ( 0 );
        endval = high.charCodeAt ( 0 );
    } else {
        inival = ( isNaN ( low ) ? 0 : low );
        endval = ( isNaN ( high ) ? 0 : high );
    }

    plus = ( ( inival > endval ) ? false : true );
    if ( plus ) {
        while ( inival <= endval ) {
            matrix.push ( ( ( chars ) ? String.fromCharCode ( inival ) : inival ) );
            inival += walker;
        }
    } else {
        while ( inival >= endval ) {
            matrix.push ( ( ( chars ) ? String.fromCharCode ( inival ) : inival ) );
            inival -= walker;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

console.log(range('A','Z')) 
// ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

This is not mine, taken from: http://javascript.ru/php/range

Answer (score 1):

No, JavaScript does not have any built-in Range object. You would need to write a function to create an abstract Range, and then add a `to_a` method for the equivalence.

For fun, here's an alternative way to get that exact output, with no intermediary strings.

```
function commaRange(startChar,endChar){
  var c=','.charCodeAt(0);
  for (var a=[],i=startChar.charCodeAt(0),e=endChar.charCodeAt(0);i<=e;++i){
    a.push(i); a.push(c);
  }
  a.pop();
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,a);
}

console.log(commaRange('A','J')); // "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J"
```

For Node.js, there is the [Lazy](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
function range(r, x) {
    var c1 = r.charCodeAt(0)+1, c2 = r.charCodeAt(3), s = r[0];
    if(c1 && c2)while (c1 <= c2) s += (x || "") + String.fromCharCode(c1++);
    return s;
}

range("A--S", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var range = [];
for(var i = 65; i < 91; i++)
{
 range.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
range = range.join(',');
```

gives range a-z, but i like the function option of some too.

Answer (score 0):

```
> let charRange = (start, end) => Array.from(new Array(end.charCodeAt(0) - start.charCodeAt(0) + 1)).map((e,i) => String.fromCharCode(start.charCodeAt(0) + i));
[Function: charRange]
> charRange('B','X');
[
  'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
  'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
  'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
  'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
  'V', 'W', 'X'
]
```