# How to generate an array of the alphabet?

Tags: javascript

In Ruby I can do `('a'..'z').to_a` to get `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ... 'z']`.

Does JavaScript provide a similar construct?

Comment: No, you need to create your own.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can easily make a *function* to do this for you if you'll need it a lot

```js
function genCharArray(charA, charZ) {
    var a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
    for (; i <= j; ++i) {
        a.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(genCharArray('a', 'z')); // ["a", ..., "z"]
```

Comment: charCodeAt(0) for i and j?

Comment: @f1f5 to get the Unicode encoding value of the first character of each argument.

Comment: I think this is the way to do it. It could also be made generic by testing the type of the arguments and returning an appropriate range, like numbers for example.

Comment: So just happened to come across this, but actually typing out a function that returns the array of character literals has less characters than this function. See my codepen: https://codepen.io/jarodsmk/pen/NYaaxx

Comment: thanks, some useful demo for small childs https://mrswed.github.io/Russian_alphabet_for_color with all letters

Comment: Super Working Fine :)

Answer (score 165):

Personally I think the best is:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

Concise, effective, legible, and simple!

**EDIT:**
I have decided, that since my answer is receiving a fair amount of attention to add the functionality to choose specific ranges of letters.

```js
function to_a(c1 = 'a', c2 = 'z') {
    a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    return (a.slice(a.indexOf(c1), a.indexOf(c2) + 1)); 
}

console.log(to_a('b', 'h'));
```

Comment: How would you accommodate `('m'..'p').to_a`, `('A'..'F').to_a` or `('1'..'5').to_a`?

Comment: @PaulS. I don't know ruby, but I will try to port it over some time today.

Comment: Little extra: If you are really lazy, you could just drag your finger across each row on your keyboard (qwertyuiop...), then use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to put the letters back in order.

Comment: To get all characters in UPPER CASE: `const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').map((c) => c.toUpperCase());`

Comment: What would you say the expected output of `to_a('A', 'z');` is? Or `to_a('α', 'ω')` @MichaelLonghurst ? Also @sonlexqt if you order your ops the other way around you save a lot of CPU; `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toUpperCase().split('')`

Comment: one big pitfall of this method is that it is subject to typo. And the person who verifies this code has to visually go through your `a` to `z`. If you loop through `a` to `z` and print out the result and it contains all characters from `a` to `z`, there cannot be any typo in that series of 26 alphabets

Comment: @PaulS. you might like the following solution:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597634/how-to-generate-an-array-of-the-alphabet/64599298#64599298

Also if you prefer my implementation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597634/how-to-generate-an-array-of-the-alphabet/76410805#76410805) then you can replace the implementation of this one with that one.

Answer (score 88):

A short ES6 version:

```js
const alphabet = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
console.log(alphabet);
```

Answer (score 55):

In case anyone came here looking for something they can hard-code, here you go:

`["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]`

Comment: Literally the same length as nonhardcoded solutions.

Comment: Haha, exactly what I want. 

Answer (score 46):

```
new Array( 26 ).fill( 1 ).map( ( _, i ) => String.fromCharCode( 65 + i ) );
```

*Use 97 instead of 65 to get the lowercase letters.*

Comment: could use `'A'.charCodeAt(0)` to remove a magic number (at a small cost to performance)

Answer (score 25):

By using ES6 spread operator you could do something like this:

```
let alphabet = [...Array(26).keys()].map(i => String.fromCharCode(i + 97));
```

Comment: Use 65 instead of 97 to get the uppercase letters.

Answer (score 17):

I saw an answer I loved above which was the hardcoded list of the english alphabets but it was in lower case only and I needed upper case too so I decided to modify it in case someone else needs it:

`const lowerAlph = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];`

`const upperCaseAlp = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];`

Comment: no, you made code block instead of inline code, which doesn't have a scollbar, triple click to select line includes your variable definition, which somebody might not want. Lower case is already there above so I put a uppercase one `['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']` (copied from yours, and somehow you have different code style)

Comment: @Valen Fixed the inline code for better readability. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 15):

A lot of these answers either use an array of characters or `String.fromCharCode`, I propose a slightly different method that takes advantage of letters in base36:

```
[...Array(26)].map((e,i)=>(i+10).toString(36))
```

The advantage of this one is purely code golf, it uses fewer characters than the others.

Comment: I haven't seen this before. Can you explain why `.toString(36)` makes it alphabets.

Comment: @RotimiBest Base 10 numbers use 10 possible characters (0-9) to represent each digit. Base 36 numbers numbers use 0-9 plus A-Z to represent all their digits. `.toString(36)` converts a base 10 number into base 36. This code creates  an array of numbers 10-35 and converts them each to base 36. 10->A, 11->B ... 35->Z.

Comment: Can you do this with upper case letters?

Comment: @Timo Append `.toUpperCase()` after `toString(36)`...

Comment: Nice new solution, that 99% have to google when they see it ^^

Answer (score 9):

in case if you need a hard-coded `array` of the alphabet, but with a less typing. an alternative solution of what mentioned above.

```
var arr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
```

will output an array like this

```
/* ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m","n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] */
```

Comment: Same as [this answer from several years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31755504/215552)...

Answer (score 6):

## Magic

```js
[...8337503854730415241050377135811259267835n.toString(36)]
```

```js
// chrome & firefox
let a1 = [...8337503854730415241050377135811259267835n.toString(36)];

console.log(a1);


// version working on all browsers (without using BigInt)
let a2 = [...[37713647386641440,2196679683172530,53605115].map(x=>x.toString(36)).join``];  

console.log(a2);
```

Comment: +1 thanks.
Kamil, would like to know more about how this works, because it does.

Comment: @MatsdeSwart puzzle hint: focus on 36

Comment: Same question here: for Base 36, there is no uppercase, because 36 is needed for 26 lowercases + numbers, right?

Comment: See the comments on [this earlier answer for hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53670054/215552).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
[...Array(26)].map((x,i)=>String.fromCharCode(i + 97))
```

```js
let alphabet = [...Array(26)].map((x,i)=>String.fromCharCode(i + 97));

console.log(alphabet);
```

Update

As you noticed in comments this idea was already used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51471587/860099) (I missed it) - but this answer is shorter so treat it as size improvement of that older answer

Answer (score 3):

**To add to @Sherwin Ablaña Dapito solution** ( I like to have some hints in answers)

- 65 is start for upper Alphabet, 26 is number of chars in Alphabet
- **fill()** method changes all elements in an array to a static value (1), in-place.
- **map()** is applied to every elem, creates a new array and has a func as arg.
- **=>** arrow function expression, can be written as `function (i){ return i+ 65;}`
- **_** in map: ignore param (placeholder value, no value here) and use second = index
- `String.fromcharcode` is self explanatory

`new Array( 26 ).fill( 1 ).map( ( _, i ) => String.fromCharCode( 65 + i ) );`

Answer (score 2):

#### Generate Character List with one-liner

```js
const charList = (a,z,d=1)=>(a=a.charCodeAt(),z=z.charCodeAt(),[...Array(Math.floor((z-a)/d)+1)].map((_,i)=>String.fromCharCode(a+i*d)));

console.log("from A to G", charList('A', 'G'));
console.log("from A to Z with step/delta of 2", charList('A', 'Z', 2));
console.log("reverse order from Z to P", charList('Z', 'P', -1));
console.log("from 0 to 5", charList('0', '5', 1));
console.log("from 9 to 5", charList('9', '5', -1));
console.log("from 0 to 8 with step 2", charList('0', '8', 2));
console.log("from α to ω", charList('α', 'ω'));
console.log("Hindi characters from क to ह", charList('क', 'ह'));
console.log("Russian characters from А to Я", charList('А', 'Я'));
```

For TypeScript

```
const charList = (p: string, q: string, d = 1) => {
  const a = p.charCodeAt(0),
    z = q.charCodeAt(0);
  return [...Array(Math.floor((z - a) / d) + 1)].map((_, i) =>
    String.fromCharCode(a + i * d)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, then you can define a getter on the Array prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'to_a', {
  get: function () {
    const start = this[0].charCodeAt(0);
    const end = this[1].charCodeAt(0);
    return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1).keys()).map(n => String.fromCharCode(start + n));
  }
});
```

Which makes it possible to do something like:

```
['a', 'z'].to_a; // [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", ..., "z" ]
```

Comment: Sebastian Simon you might like this solution.

Also if you prefer my implementation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597634/how-to-generate-an-array-of-the-alphabet/76410805#76410805) then you can replace the implementation of this one with that one.

Comment: Also we could define this property for the `String` `prototype` (instead of the `Array` one) and then do `'az'.to_a`.

Comment: For production code, would not recommend extending the prototype of a built-in unless you're writing a polyfill to the ecmascript spec (in which case why not also open source it). You could end up with unexpected behaviour with other people's code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick one-liner

No dependencies!

```
Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65).map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x));
```

```js
console.log(Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65).map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let name = ''

for(let i=0; i<26; i++){
  name+=(i+10).toString(36)
}

console.log(name.split(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

//using map 1 line code

```
let alphabet =[...Array(26)].map( (_,i) => String.fromCharCode(65+i) )
```

// using array for inserting A-Z

```
let newArray = []
for(var i = 0; i<26 ; i++){
  newArray.push(String.fromCharCode(65+i))
}
```

// using array for inserting a-z

```
let newArray = []
for(var i = 0`enter code here`; i<26 ; i++){
  newArray.push(String.fromCharCode(65+i).toLowerCase())
}
```

//using split

```
 let a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1 }, (_, i) => start + (i * step));

let alpha  = range('A'.charCodeAt(0), 'Z'.charCodeAt(0), 1).map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x));
// ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
console.log(alpha);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
const chars = [];
for (let i=65; i<=65+25; i++){
  chars.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}

console.log(chars, Array.isArray((chars )));
```

Comment: Use `97` and `97 + 25` to get an array of lowercase letters

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript's Array.from syntax allows you to create an array and perform a mapping function on each of the array elements. Create a new array of length 26 and on each element set the value equal to the string obtained from the char code of the index of the current element plus the ascii magic number.

```
const alphabet = Array.from(Array(26), (e, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97));
```

Again, 97 may be interchanged with 65 for an uppercase alphabet.

The array may also be initialized with values using the object's keys method rather than utilising the index of the map

```
const alphabet = Array.from(Array(26).keys(), i => String.fromCharCode(i + 97));
```

Comment: No need to pass in an array, you only need an object with a length property. { length: 26 }

Answer (score 0):

```
const ALPHA = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode('a'.charCodeAt(0) + i)); // ['a', 'b', ...'z']
```

I believe the above code is more idiomatic. Short enough to be an inline code.
You don't have to remember the charCode of your start letter and configurable to retrieve subsets of the alphabet by simply controlling the length and start letter e.g

```
Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode('x'.charCodeAt(0) + i)) // ['x', 'y', 'z]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this:

```js
[...Array(26).keys()].map(n => n + 'a'.codePointAt(0)).map(ch => String.fromCharCode(ch))
```

Answer (score 0):

See result

```js
function getAsciiToString(from, total) {
  let count = 0;
  let asciiLetters = "";

  while (count < total) {
    const asciiDigit = from.charCodeAt(0) + count;
    asciiLetters += String.fromCharCode(asciiDigit);
    count++;
  }

  return asciiLetters;
}

console.log(getAsciiToString("a", 26));
console.log(getAsciiToString("A", 26));
console.log(getAsciiToString("0", 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient as there are no wasted temporary arrays.

```js
const alphabetLowerCase = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + i));

console.log(alphabetLowerCase);

const alphabetUpperCase = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(65 + i));

console.log(alphabetUpperCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following:

```js
var result = ''

for (
    let character = 'a'

    ; character <= 'z'

    ; character = String.fromCharCode(
        character.charCodeAt() + 1
    )
)
    result += character

console.log(result)
```

Here `result` is already an array-like object, but if you would need it as an actual array you could do the following instead:

```js
var result = []

for (
    let character = 'a'

    ; character <= 'z'

    ; character = String.fromCharCode(
        character.charCodeAt() + 1
    )
)
    result.push(character)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Looks good logically and can be easily adjusted to work over any sequence of chars. Would be interesting to see memory, CPU and garbage collection implications of the different ways to build the output 

Comment: You can save yourself a decode if you store the numeric value, but that would then be very similar to my answer

Comment: Yes, my goal was to literally write what I want to do as much as possible.

Yes, basically your answer is that, which is a little faster.

Answer (score -1):

No Javascript or Jquery doesnot provide anything like that. You have to create your own array.

You may try like this:

```
var alpha = ["a","b","c",....];
```

or better try like this:

```
var index = 97;
$("#parent .number").each(function(i) {
    $(this).html(String.fromCharCode(index++));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/agKrz/17/)**

Comment: I really think he probably wants something a little more automated than manually typing out the entire alphabet. Seems clear from the question that he already knows how to create an array.

Comment: @cookiemonster:- Updated my answer with a demo! Hope that helps OP!

Comment: Something a little more directly relevant to the question might be to use `$.map()` to create an Array. `$.map(Array(26), function(_, i) { return String.fromCharCode(i + 97); })` http://jsfiddle.net/agKrz/18/

Comment: @cookie post as answer. I like that best :)

Comment: @f1f5: I think the answer posted by Paul S is much better. I was mostly just providing an alternative that didn't rely on DOM elements.

Comment: the second code seems to be even longer than just write all the letters out, like this `var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');`

Comment: why on the demo the very last character is "}" - a curly brace?

Answer (score -1):

var arr = ["C", "D", "X", "A", "B", "Z"]; console.log(arr.sort( function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b) })); // ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'Z']