# include multiple parts using ngInclude

Tags: html, angularjs

I am making a `WebApp` with `angularJS` and I have something that irritates me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>webapp</title>
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div class="container">
    <h1>WebApp</h1>
    <div ng-controller="home as homeCtrl" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" class="wrapper">
        <div ng-include="'blocks/item.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/something.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/health.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/mana.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/running.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/out.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/of.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'blocks/ideas.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Every item, i have to write another include. is there a way to include these and any additions in the future with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your controller create the alphabet array ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597634/how-to-generate-an-array-of-alphabet-in-jquery))

```
function genCharArray(charA, charZ) {
    var a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
    for (; i <= j; ++i) {
        a.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
    return a;
}
$scope.charArray = genCharArray('a', 'z'); // ["a", ..., "z"]
```

Then, in your template:

```
<div ng-controller="home as homeCtrl" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" class="wrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="letter in charArray" ng-include="'blocks/' + letter + '.html'"></div>
</div>
```

[edit]
If you want to work with any generic list and not specifically the alphabet as in the original post, just use an array and initialize it with whatever.

```
$scope.charArray = ['lemon', 'tree', 'apple'];
```

The point here is using `ng-repeat` to iterate over any number of objects you like, and dynamically create the `ng-include` elements appropriately.

Comment: sorry. i used the alfabet as placeholder for the filenames. This may work in that case but not the one i have.

Comment: Edited my answer, but just initialize the array with anything you like.