# Is there a simple way I can populate an Array with objects containing an id and name from A to Z?

Tags: javascript

Currently my code is doing this:

```
wordLetterSelect = [
    {
        id: 'A',
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 'B',
        name: 'B'
    }
];
```

But I need to do it for every character in the alphabet. Is there a simple way that I could do this without just repeating one character after the other in the same way as I have done for A and B?

**Update**

The possible duplicate question does something similar but does not do what I am looking for. Hope someone can help with this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate an array of alphabet in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597634/how-to-generate-an-array-of-alphabet-in-jquery) .you can push objects to array

Comment: answer is not using jquery .also you can split a string as 2nd answer.then dynamically push objects to array

Comment: The other question does explain something similar but I'm not sure how to make this generate the array of objects like I need.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mvk9g7hq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var wordLetterSelect = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('').map(function(param){ 
   return {
        id: param,
        name: param
   };
});
```

Of course you can do the same with a loop if you don't like the map thing.

Comment: This is giving me a message saying "cannot find name obj"

Comment: Why not do `A..Z` and spare yourself the `.toUppercase()`s?

Comment: You are either setting a global variable named `obj`, or getting a ReferenceError.

Answer (score 5):

Use this sample (**no maps required**):

```
var wordLetterSelect = [];

for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {

  var letter = String.fromCharCode(i);

  wordLetterSelect.push({id: letter, name: letter});
}

console.log(wordLetterSelect);
```

This code generates an object with letters from their codes. `65` is **A**, `66` - **B** ... `90` - **Z**.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode()` returns a string, you can simply assign to the `letter`, without concatenating

Answer (score 2):

use a loop.you can create and push objects to array.

```
wordLetterSelect = [];
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
for(var i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++){
    wordLetterSelect.push({id:alphabet[i],name:alphabet[i]});
}
console.log(wordLetterSelect);
```

Comment: you can use `toUpperCase()` or UpperCase string if you want uppercase letters

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getLetter = n => String.fromCharCode(n + 65);

var wordLetterSelect = new Array(26).fill(0).map((_, i) => ({
    id: getLetter(i),
    letter: getLetter(i)
}));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(wordLetterSelect, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```