# Loop over character and increment it inside loop JS

Tags: javascript

How can I create loop like this in JS?

```
for (var ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
console.log(ch)
}
```

Comment: Someone else suggested [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597634/how-to-generate-an-array-of-the-alphabet) would also help, but that comment got deleted by the system when the question was closed. It's certainly relevant though.

Comment: but I dont just want to increment it, I need to call Trie function for each function inside for loop, so need to know how can I increment like ch++, inside the loop

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a character type, just strings with one character. Its strings are UTF-16 code unit sequences (details in my blog post [*What is a String?*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/)), so you can start with `n = "a".charCodeAt(0)` (97) and loop while `n <= "z".charCodeAt(0)` (122) and output the result of `String.fromCharCode(n)`. If you needed to do something similar but in the realm of characters that require multiple code units, the equivalent operations are `.codePointAt` and `String.fromCodePoint`.