# How to run coffeescript file with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I use coffee script to writing my node.js app. When I write an .coffeescript file and run it. It will compile into top-level function javascript and this make my code didn't run.

Ex:

app.coffee

```
console.log "Hello world";
```

Will automatically compile into

```
(function() {
    console.log("Hello world");
}).call(this)
```

And this make node app.coffee didn't run.

Can you help me whenever I run `node app.coffee` it will compile my coffeescript with `-bare` option?

Comment: If you're getting errors, what are they? If by "not run" you mean "doesn't produce any output", say that specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you run cofeescript with `node app.coffee`?

According to [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679782/can-i-use-coffeescript-instead-of-js-for-node-js) it is impossible. You have to either compile it first and then run, i.e.

```
coffee -c app.coffee
node app.js
```

or use the coffee to run it for you, i.e.

```
coffee app.coffee
```

Nevertheles, I can't see how the wrapper function generated by coffee could "make the app did not run".

Comment: you can run it as ``coffee app.coffee -n``